# Why is MatLab giving such a weirdly scaled Nyquist plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, transfer-function, nyquist

I wrote this code:

```
s = tf('s');
P = (s+35)/(s*(s+3.5)*(s+3500));
nyquist(P)
```

which resulted in this very weirdly scaled plot:

[image]

which, if I zoom WAY in, looks like this:

[image]

There's clearly something weird going on with the scaling, as it made the arrows *ridiculously* large, resulting in the main part of the plot being unreasonably small even after zooming in, but the weird thing is that it will create a bode plot of the same transfer function with no issue, and, similarly, if I do, e.g. `nyquist((2+s)/s^2)`, I get this, which looks perfectly reasonable:
[image]

Why is it giving such a weird result for one function and a perfectly result for another?  And how do I fix it so it automatically uses reasonable scaling without my having zoom way in and so it doesn't make the arrows insanely big?  AFAIK, I haven't done anything to change the default plotting settings, as I'm not seeing anything like this for any other plots.

I've also looked at the documentation on the `nyquist` function and I didn't see anything there that mentions scaling or the like.

Comment: Looks like a bug, you should submit this to MathWorks so they can fix it.